# Add classes to two level navigation with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, menu

I have a simple navigation with two levels.  The li-elements of the first level shall get class="n11", that of the second class="n12".

This will write class="n11" to every li-element.

```js
var firstNavi = document.getElementsByClassName("nav1-1");
for(var i = 0; i < firstNavi.length; i++) {
    var firstLi = firstNavi[i].querySelectorAll("li");
    for(var i = 0; i < firstLi.length; i++) {
        firstLi[i].classList.add("n11");
    }
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav1-1">
    <li ><a href="">1.1.</a></li>
    <li ><a href="">1.2</a>
        <ul class="nav1-2">
            <li><a href="">1.2.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">1.2.2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">1.3</a>
        <ul class="nav1-2">
            <li><a href="">1.3.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">1.3.2</a></li>
        </ul>
    <li><a href="">1.4</a></li>
</ul>
```

How to achieve that is written class="n12" to the second li-elements and class="n11" only to the first level entries? Thanks for any help.

Comment: var i = 0 and var i = 0??? nested variables in your loop. The inside loop needs to be something that is not `i`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just retrieve the first level `<li>` elements as well as the second level `<li>` elements by using the [child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator) `>` on the first level parent `<ul>` element and the second level `<ul>` parent element and now you can just loop through each list element and add the class name accordingly like this:

```js
const firstLevel = document.querySelectorAll('.nav1-1 > li');
const secondLevel = document.querySelectorAll('.nav1-2 > li');

for (var i = 0; i < firstLevel.length; i++) {
  firstLevel[i].classList.add('n11');
}
for (var i = 0; i < secondLevel.length; i++) {
  secondLevel[i].classList.add('n12');
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav1-1">
    <li ><a href="">1.1.</a></li>
    <li ><a href="">1.2</a>
        <ul class="nav1-2">
            <li><a href="">1.2.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">1.2.2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">1.3</a>
        <ul class="nav1-2">
            <li><a href="">1.3.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">1.3.2</a></li>
        </ul>
    <li><a href="">1.4</a></li>
</ul>
```

---

If you do not care about IE 11 compatibility or you are using a JavaScript compiler like Babel, you can further shorten and simplify the above JavaScript by using the [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method and arrow functions like this:

```js
const firstLevel = document.querySelectorAll('.nav1-1 > li');
const secondLevel = document.querySelectorAll('.nav1-2 > li');

firstLevel.forEach(e => e.classList.add('n11'));
secondLevel.forEach(e => e.classList.add('n12'));
```

```html
<ul class="nav1-1">
    <li ><a href="">1.1.</a></li>
    <li ><a href="">1.2</a>
        <ul class="nav1-2">
            <li><a href="">1.2.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">1.2.2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">1.3</a>
        <ul class="nav1-2">
            <li><a href="">1.3.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">1.3.2</a></li>
        </ul>
    <li><a href="">1.4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ">" query selector to find `li` elements that have a parent of `.nav1-1`, then add class `n11` to each.  Rinse and repeat for the `li` elements that have a parent of `.nav1-2`.

Here it is in code.

```js
'use strict';

const li1s = document.querySelectorAll('.nav1-1 > li');

for (const li of li1s)
  li.classList.add('n11');

const li2s = document.querySelectorAll('.nav1-2 > li');

for (const li of li2s)
  li.classList.add('n12');
```

```html
<ul class="nav1-1">
    <li ><a href="">1.1.</a></li>
    <li ><a href="">1.2</a>
        <ul class="nav1-2">
            <li><a href="">1.2.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">1.2.2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">1.3</a>
        <ul class="nav1-2">
            <li><a href="">1.3.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">1.3.2</a></li>
        </ul>
    <li><a href="">1.4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you all so much for your help, I did not no that there is such a thing like an ">"-query-selector. Both solutions works like a charm. You saved so much time.

Comment: You bet, glad to help.

Comment: @AndrewL64 - Well, both answers are pretty neat. So I give both you an upvote.